# Kazam video files don't load in Windows

Tags: kazam

I recently screen recorded my first Ubuntu video. I saved it to my desktop and when I play it, it works fine.

But when I copy the video (mp4 format) to my local disk c drive and reboot it to windows to play it. It gives me an error "Bad file descriptor"

How do I export my Ubuntu screen recorded files to windows.

Comment: You have to recode using avconv from libav-tools, 
avconv -i MyMovie.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 64k -threads 4 -y MyMovieForWindows.mp4. Not all options are needed the "pix_fmt yuv420p" is essential I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While MP4 can contain many different codecs, [Kazam's codecs](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kazam-team/kazam/stable/view/head:/kazam/backend/prefs.py#L393) are quite straight forward. It's h.264.

This is a fairly universal codec these days but I wouldn't be surprised if you still needed to [download a decoder codec](https://code.google.com/p/lavfilters/) for Windows.